# Moving DataTables pagination length dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to move the  dropdown that DataTables uses to determine how many rows to display. One way I thought of was to use jQuery's prependTo()/appendTo() functions, but it feels a bit too hack-y. I tried searching through the DataTables API to see if there was some native way of doing it, but I couldn't find anything. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

This is basically what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jbZG7/

```
$("#tableID").dataTable();
$("#tableID_length").prependTo("#new-div-id");
```

Thanks!

Comment: the sDom config option will let you re-order it relative to other datatables features. you can also safely append the <select> somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me as I'm trying to place it in a <div> that's entirely separate from DataTables. I tried it out, and AFAIK it simply either adds a custom <div> within the DataTables wrapper, not move the element to another location.

Comment: you have to wait for datatables to inject in the markup and bind the clicks and all that, then you can append the feature's wrapper div, #ID_FEATURE, anywhere else in the document. i've done this extensively with a grid i've been working on all week, moving stuff into a responsive top toolbar, so i can assure you it's possible. you can also just makeup your own <select onchange="oTable.fnSettings()._iDisplayLength=+this.value; oTable.draw()"> and put that anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom dataTables widget which combined jQuery UI Dialog with DataTables.  I too needed to move dataTable controls to custom locations, which could not be accomplished with sDOM very much in the same way you need to.

When looking for a solutions I was concerned about .appendTo/.prependTo being too hacky, but as it turns out .appendTo/.prependTo are the best solutions I have found.

```js
$('tableID').dataTable({
  fnInitComplete : function( oSettings, json ){
   $("#tableID_length").detach().prependTo("#new-div-id");
  }
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/jbZG7/1/)

[fnInitComplete](http://datatables.net/ref#fnInitComplete)

Answer (score -2):

Open the dataTables.js file. Look inside and see if you can find anything related to paging. I did a CTRL+F and typed pagination. You want to look for information on where the pager is drawn.

Also...using firebug to set breakpoints in the dataTables.js file might be a big help too.

Comment: Modifying the core of DataTable.js is an extremely hacky solution and the OP is explicitly looking to avoid hackish solutions.